# #if DEBUG doesn't seem to work in my VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've been doing the following in my C# code:

```
#if DEBUG
//Debugger only code
#endif
```

But for some reason when I do the same in my C# console application (that is built as a Windows service in VS 2010) it doesn't seem to work and for both Release and Debug configurations it looks like `DEBUG` is not defined.

Do I need to set something for that preprocessor constant to work?

Comment: Look in the project properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using the 'Debug' configuration, you have to go to project's Properties -> Build
and tick the 'Define DEBUG constant' box.

Either that, or define the conditional compilation symbol: DEBUG. As you can do with any other custom compilation symbol :)

Comment: OK. It did it. Thanks. For some reason it'd define it by default, but not this time....

Comment: @c00000fd No problem, such situations are sometimes hard to diagnose. Glad I could help :)